# PostGIS query is slower using a spatial index

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, indexing, postgis

Working on an free online database course with tasks, I came across a problem with spatial indizes that I cannot understand. I have a dataset with about 10.000 points and 300 polygons. A query should be made, which points are contained in the polygons using NO spatial index. After that, an index should be created and the query done again. There should be an improvement in the performance.

But in my case, I get the opposite of the expected result: instead of making my query faster, the query even gets slower. I double checked that I correctly created the index. The index is a spatial index set up on the geometry of the points.

The query only runs for about 2 seconds without the index and about 2.2, 2.4 seconds with the index. Why could this possibly happen?

Comment: Could you pleas share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement, the SQL statement itself and the DDL for the tables and indexes involved? All in plain text, as an update of your question.

Comment: I will do so. But in general, could it happen with small datasets that an index makes the query slower?

Comment: In many cases an index is not even used on smaller data sets. And when you force the database to use the index, the query might become slower. The query plan will show you.

Comment: It is indeed possible that an index makes a query be slower than without it. However, normally postgres chooses not to use this index and opts for a seq scan. Add the query and the query plan to your question ... maybe the answer is in there ;) cheers